# Can I publish open graph story in background?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have android application.
I need to post messages to FB on some user actions.

As I understand from brief documentation read:

1. I can do it without specific permissions but using FB share popup. User should type some message here
2. I can publish open graph stories in background. But I need publish_actions permission for that. Also need some confirm popup before publish so that user to be aware of this. But I can set messages I need without ability for user to change text.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I really *hope* you can't post to a user's timeline without their permission or knowledge. If you figure out a way, I'm sure your app will be off facebook in seconds.

Comment: I undersand that, But not clear what means "their permission or knowledge" exactly